# Using select statement to repeat process in bash script

Tags: bash, loops, select, sed, grep

I'm super close to finishing my assignment but I'm a little stumped on one part.

Here's what I got:

```
for file in $1
do
    wget "$1" -O "output-$1.html" -q
    cat output-$1.html | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | 
    sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | 
    sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d' | 
    grep 'http' > ~/bcache/$1.bcache

select LINK in `cat ~/bcache/$1.bcache` "q_to_quit"
    do
        if [ $LINK = "q_to_quit" ] 
           then
             exit 1
           else 
               repeat lines 3-7
        fi
    done
```

Lines 3-7 take a url and output to an html file, where that html file is then sorted through with grep and sed to only pull out "http://...", which is then put into a file which is stored into a directory called bcache.

The select statement prints out all of the "http://..." with numbers preceding them, with the last option being q_to_quit.

I can't figure out how to repeat the process of lines 3 through 7 once someone enters a number (which corresponds to a url, which needs to be sorted, saved, and stored, rinse and repeat.)

Comment: You might consider re-executing the same script, using a new argument: `exec "$0" "$LINK"`

Comment: What is the purpose of the `for` loop?

Comment: @Ramana No, that doesn't work at all and you [Don't Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for` loop will only loop once (ideally) since `$1` should only be a single word (and should be quoted, `"$1"`, to ensure that whatever the value you are given is used correctly).

So you probably don't need it.

If you were trying to have that support multiple arguments being passed to the script then you want `for file in "$@"` (or just `for file` which is the same thing) but this doesn't really work well with the rest of the scripts operation it seems to me.

Given the above to get the effect you actually want you put the loop body in a `while true` or `while :` loop and using `$LINK` in those top lines instead of `$1`.

```
LINK=$1

while :; do
    wget "$LINK" -O "output-$LINK.html" -q
    cat "output-$LINK.html" | grep -o '<a .*href=.*>' | 
    sed -e 's/<a /\n<a /g' | 
    sed -e 's/<a .*href=['"'"'"]//' -e 's/["'"'"'].*$//' -e '/^$/ d' | 
    grep 'http' > ~/bcache/"$LINK.bcache"

    select LINK in `cat ~/bcache/"$LINK.bcache"` "q_to_quit"
    do
        if [ $LINK = "q_to_quit" ] 
        then
            exit 1
        else 
            break
        fi
    done
done
```

Also, as I just put in a comment on the OP you shouldn't [Read Lines With `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Comment: @glennjackman Ah, true. I always forget that `select` self-loops. Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response, as well as the article on why not to use for loops for reading in lines. I'll give it a read through. My issue now comes in with the execution after the while loop begins. I am getting errors 
"certain directory does not exist" so I believe I am doing this incorrectly

Comment: However, I will accept the answer because it was the answer to my question. Thank you! :)

Comment: `output-http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi.html: No such file or directory
cat: output-http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi.html: No such file or directory` after an initial `./navigator google.com` where I then pressed 1, to loop the first link back into the while

Comment: What is your initial input to the script? That's certainly true. You can't put slashes in a filename so those are going to have gotten dropped or translated at some point.

Comment: `./navigator.sh google.com`
This gave me a list of the URL's, the first being: `1) http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi`. When asked for a selection I entered 1, and got the error above.

Comment: @MikeHenke, that's because you're trying to create a filename with slashes in it -- can't do that. You need to translate the slashes to another character for wget's output file.